# Azure VSCode deployment fails with Updating iisnode.yml

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I generated a bot with yo teams, created the bot registration on Azure and then attempted to deploy it using Azure App Service extension.

The deployment fails with:

2:15:38 p.m. ktsbot: Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\iisnode.yml
2:15:38 p.m. ktsbot: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\iisnode.yml'
2:15:38 p.m. ktsbot: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
2:15:38 p.m. ktsbot: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\iisnode.yml'\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\87.20522.4610\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd deploy.cmd
2:15:46 p.m. ktsbot: Deployment failed.

In the console I cd to wwwroot and the "\dist" directory does not exist.
iisnode.yml is in the wwwroot directory.

I am at a loss - thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?